# sql query using group by how to do

Tags: sql

I have a table **Details** with following values

```
**id     name   locale    code**
   1     Zen    GR        101
   2     Ryan   IN        105
   3     Rico   GR        101
   4     Susan  GR        101
   5     Tom    AU        106
   6     John   AU        107
   7     Lis    AU        107
```

I need to select all rows which has code count greater than 2. And tried with this query

```
select *
from Details
group by code
having count(code)>2
```

returns result:

```
1     Zen    GR        101
6     John   AU        107
```

but i want this:

```
   1     Zen    GR        101
   3     Rico   GR        101
   4     Susan  GR        101
   6     John   AU        107
   7     Lis    AU        107
```

Please help me to do this
Thanks

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A generic SQL way is to use the `in` operator:

```
select *
from Details d
where d.code in (select code
                 from Details
                 group by code
                 having count(code) > 2
                ) ;
```

There are other ways of writing this, depending on the database (and some might perform faster than this in particular databases).

EDIT:

A nice way to do this in many databases is using window/analytic functions:

```
select id, name, locale, code
from (select d.*, count(*) over (partition by code) as codecnt
      from details d
     ) d
where codecnt > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.. I will go for option 1.